# How often are the system performance counter values updated?

Tags: .net, performancecounter

In my application I am monitoring some of the system's performance counters (CPU usage) during the execution of the operation. I added a timer that will look at the performance counter value, store it and at the end of the operation i am monitoring, get an average of the retrieved values.

My question is how often does it make sense to query the performance counters for an updated value. After what interval of time will the performance counter value be updated? I have the timer set up at 200 ms